# MySQL Return Unique Categories in Top 10 Products

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I am returning the top 10 products based on a score, simple enough, along with a related product type table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN product_types ON products .product_type_id=product_types.id 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

That gives me the products but seperately, I want to be able to also return the unique list of product types *within that top 10* and I can't figure out how.  I tried using distinct and just the type_name column but the limit option appears to apply to a limit of 10 product_types instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT type_name 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN product_types ON products .product_type_id=product_types.id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

I've tried group by but I couldn't work out how to get that to work with the JOINs.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: So, in case 6 of those 10 product share types, you'd want to get only the 5 types, instead of the 'top 10 ' types, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_types.product_type_name
FROM products
INNER JOIN product_types ON products.product_type_id = product_types.id
ORDER BY products.score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This query will return a list of unique product types from the top 10 products, sorted by score. The DISTINCT keyword ensures that each product type is only listed once in the output, even if multiple products of the same type are in the top 10.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your original query as a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type_name
FROM (
    SELECT type_name
    FROM products p
    INNER JOIN product_types pt ON p.product_type_id = pt.id 
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 10
) t;
```

Or you could do it in your client application by just iterating over the existing result set, creating a unique array of the type_names.